# Creating audio visualizer that works with streaming audio

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for audio visualizations for Streaming music. All the templates I find on the Internet takes an MP3 file as input, buffers, and then visualizes it. Is there a code out there doing Visualization for streaming audio?

I've found these links so far:

http://ianreah.com/2013/02/28/Real-time-analysis-of-streaming-audio-data-with-Web-Audio-API.html

https://github.com/scrapjs/render